# persist screen resolution in UBUNTU 13.04

Tags: 13.04, resolution, screen

I've installed Ubuntu 13.04, but I cant persist the screen resolution. It take by default the 1024x768, but I want to configure it with 1280x1024. These commands:

```
xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00" 109.00 1280 1368 1496 1712 1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
```

and then

```
xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1280x1024_60.00"
```

These two commands works well, but I dont want to run these two every time I boot my PC!!
I tried to persist this configuration in the /etc/X11/XSession, but isnt working.

Can you please give a way to persist this in Ubuntu 13.04?

Its very strange, because in previous version of Ubuntu, persist screen resolution configuration wasn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `xrandr -s 1280x1024`

Comment: Hello, it works fine, but what I want is to persist the configuration. I tried editing the xorg.conf, but this file doesnt exist.

Comment: @user183086 If xorg.conf doesn't exist you can simply create it if you know what to put in to it. However, it's possible the computer won't boot if put there something that shouldn't be there... That's easily rectifiable, though. Just say if you're going to attempt it, I will give you the steps how to recover if something goes wrong. And if nothing works you can still use the command I mentioned and make it automatically run at boot.

Comment: hello, again. I tried with doing this: sudo X -configure but throws me an error, something that the server has already started. So what are the commands for reconfigure the X server? Besides, if the only way to persist the configuration is running the command, how can I make it run every time the system boots? Thank you very much.